# How can I set the `insertOne` function to accept duplicates?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying to upload some data to my MongoDB from a Node.js script, at the moment it will upload about 5 sets of data and return this error:

```
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: database.customers index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('5cf7a6e9b4957b3848e7cac4') }
```

I think this is due to some data records in my JSON being the same (specifically the process), however this isn't an issue.

I have tried to use the `.createIndex()` function however I am not too sure how to fully integrate that with my `.insertOne()` function.

```
data= {
                            'Process': varprocess,
                            'Number' : idnumber,   



                    }

                    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
                        if (err) throw err;
                        var dbo = db.db("mydatabase");
                        dbo.collection("customers").insertOne(data, function(err, res) {
                        if (err) throw err;
                        console.log("1 document inserted");
                        db.close();
                        });
                    });

{
    "data": [
            {
            "Process": "Process1",
            "Number": "00000",
         },
         {
            "Process": "Process1",
            "Number": "00001",
        }
    ]
}
```

I am expecting it to upload data regardless of duplicates, as you can see it doesn't like 'Process1' being entered more than once. What can I do so that all of my data is sent to the DB without errors?

thanks

Comment: The error message says you're trying to create a duplicate primary key. There are more fields in your objects that you're not showing us.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yes thats true I removed them for simplification of the question. Can't the same solution for just this instance be applied across the others?

Comment: Not sure what you meant there, but solution to unique index constraint violation is to not insert duplicate data.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev but in this case duplicate data is no issue, I need it in there as there are many instances of a single process. How could I set `unique` to false in my code?

Comment: Again, duplicate IDs are the issue (field `_id`, not field `Process`). You cannot have duplicate ids. That's their whole _raison d'être_. You can't turn that off. Fix your data to not have duplicate ids.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev ah okay that makes sense, how could i go about fixing data? How is `_id` assigned?

Comment: Presumably, you have ids in your json files (or however you store data to be inserted). So if you don't need specific values for the ids, simply remove that field from json objects. This will cause them to have a brand new id upon insertion.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I have no id field, the id is generated automatically by the Mongo server

Comment: No, I don't think so. You wouldn't have that error, if this were the case. _Something_ is happening not how you describe it.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev How do you mean something?

Comment: I mean, there's not enough info (code/data) in the question for me to reproduce the error.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev the data creation and Mongo db connection all sits inside a for loop, could it be the same key is being generated at the start of every loop iteration?